# Access Redshift Using npgsql .NET 6.0

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, npgsql

I have been trying to use the npgsql code below to access an AWS Redshift database but I am unsure as to what my host server and database is. Please help if possible and also let me know if there is a better way to do this using .Net 6.0.

```
var connString = "Host=myserver;Username=mylogin;Password=mypass;Database=mydatabase";

await using var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connString);
await conn.OpenAsync();

// Insert some data
await using (var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("INSERT INTO data (some_field) VALUES ($1)", conn))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Hello world");
    await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
}

// Retrieve all rows
await using (var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT some_field FROM data", conn))
await using (var reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync())
{
    while (await reader.ReadAsync())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(reader.GetString(0));
    }
}
```

Comment: You server, database and similar details should be visible in your AWS portal, where you configure your Redshift instance.

Comment: Host={{host}};Database={{database}};Username={{username}};Password={{password}};Port={{port}};Server Compatibility Mode=Redshift;SSL Mode=Require;Trust Server Certificate=true

taken from https://github.com/npgsql/efcore.pg/issues/1030